# Project management software, available options

Tags: git, project-management

Hey, sorry for posting this here, I know that this question better suites into SuperUser, but I would like to know answers from developers point of view.

I have been using Indefero for project management etc. for some time, but I found that Indefero limitations are too big for my team.

I'm searching project-management software that best suites this needs:

- Open-Source, but I can consider commercial apps
- GIT integration is mandatory, best if it can support multiple repos per project
- Time-tracking, good if it can have Gannt chart connected with issues etc.
- Issue, milestone, task tracking
- Good if it can be integrated with Gitosis, or have similar repository access control
- It must have an option, to setup on our own server
- Markdown syntax support is mandatory (or easy way to install plugin for this etc.)
- Issue tagging will be and advantage

It will be used by developers team by 99% of time, but it has to have some simple interface, that clients can fill up bug reports etc. per project.

It does not have to fill all this needs, but good if it can :)

What options do You know, and can recommend?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423977/good-open-source-project-management-software

Comment: @Mathias I'm waiting for a personal recommendations, not a flat list of an options, thats why I've started a new thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/).

1) Yes

2) Each project can be configured to read a repository; git included.

3) I'm not positive it does this out-of-the-box, but there are plugins available that are easy to install.

4) Yes, yes (but called "versions" instead of "milestones"), and yes (Tasks have different types: bug, feature, etc. etc, and customizable)

5) It does not control your git repository, only reads from it.  You can use Gitosis on the server to control access, and create a read-only user that Redmine can use.

6) Yes, it's open source and actively developed.

7) Update: there are Markdown [plungins](https://github.com/bitherder/redmine_markdown_formatter) [available](https://github.com/juno/redmine_markdown_extra_formatter):

[Installing plugins in Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/plugins)

Comment: Is there no alternatives to Redmine? :)

Comment: @canni: I don't know, but is there any reason you wouldn't use Redmine? It appears to meet all of your requirements.

Comment: Redmine have drawbacks too, and some of them are realy pain in my ***, for example:

lack of markdown support (or i just cant install it on redmine 1.1.0), textile markup... ouful, lack of tags (there is plugin for this, but works only with mysql, witch i dont use/have)

And few others

Comment: It sounds like your list of constraints is longer than what you posted in your question...

Comment: @bstpierre, Yep right, I've edided my question

Comment: Updated my answer to include links to available Markdown plugins and a link on how to install plugins.

Comment: @ctshryock, I've working instance of Redmine, and I've moved one project to it for testing. I've installed latest 1.1.0 instance, but those plugins produces some weird errors on my attemt to install them, I'm not a ruby guy, to be able to fix those problems, it seems that those plugins do not work wit 1.1.0 redmine version

Comment: I've forced up the markdown syntax, it seems that only thing that is missing in redmine, witch i need is tagging...

Comment: Alternative Redmine would be http://chiliproject.org

Answer (score 2):

Give [indefero.net](http://indefero.net) a try.

They have a paid for version that the developer manages, but the software itself is also open-source so you can install it to your own hardware.

It is very similar to code.google.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what to recommend, but I can tell your your entire staff will hate you forever if you buy a product called Clarity to do this. Worst piece of software of any type that I have ever used.

Answer (score 0):

[Private Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/portfolio/private-install), if you strongly against [hosted Assembla Portfolio](http://portfolio.assembla.com/)

I don't use Private, but rather happy with hosted (which share the same codebase)

Answer (score -1):

I have used many open source software, however, I am not happy with the features that they provide. So I decided to opt for a paid one and will recommend you also the same. It's been 7 months and I am using Microsoft Project 2010, a perfect [project manager software](http://www.microsoft.com/project/en/us/strategic-planning.aspx) which is very easy and simple to use; also helps in project managers in managing their project properly.

Comment: does it have any source control integation?

Comment: it does not integrate in versioning - or does it?